# jqgrid: Adjust the text width in the cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a property for jqgrid to have the cell size adjusted according to the text that fits into it, like can we move the text to next line if actually text is bigger than width of the row(that will be auto-adjusting width of column)? Now, i am having to pull the column line to see the whole text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately jqgrid doesn't support this feature. I had the same problem

Comment: Did you have a work around, i think its going to be pain to drag and find what the text is..

Comment: There were 2 workarounds. 1) Show the full content as tooltip and 2) make the row to grow vertically so the content fits. Ar they useful to you?

Comment: I believe the second one will be useful not quite sure how to implement though